# Chrome desktopCapture API with MediaStreamRecorder library

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I am trying to implement Chrome desktopCapture API with [MediaStreamRecorder library](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder). Everything works perfect but the video quality is so blurred and bad. 1 minute desktop captured video takes 14MB.

below is my code:

```
 var pending_request_id;

 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
 startRecording();
 sendResponse({"success": true});
  });

function getUserMediaError() {
console.log("getUserMedia() failed.");
}

function onAccessApproved(id) {
 if (!id) {
 console.log("Access rejected.");
 return;
 }
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
     audio:false,
    video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                        chromeMediaSourceId: id } }
  }, onMediaSuccess, getUserMediaError);
}

function startRecording()  {
pending_request_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
   ["window"], onAccessApproved);
}



function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
 console.log("rcvd stream");
 var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
 mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'video/mp4';

 //i dont want strechy video so i fixed the width and height of recorder equal to window
mediaRecorder.width = window.screen.width; 
mediaRecorder.height = window.screen.height;

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {

    var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log('<a href="' + blobURL + '">' + blobURL + '</a>');


    var link=blobURL;
var videoInfo="Compiled Video file size: " + Math.ceil(blob.size / 1024) + "KB";

console.log(link);
console.log(videoInfo);

};
mediaRecorder.start(30000); // i want unlimited recording time so i increased the timeslice
  stream.onended = function() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
  //finalizeVideo();
  console.log("Ended"); };
   }


function onMediaError(e) {
console.error('media error', e);
}
```

Before using this library i tried to save streaming video using Whammy.js. but i failed to do so. then i found this library.

Questions :

Is there any way to increase quality of the video and as well as compress video size too?

How to save the video which return as *blob:chrome* url to desktop as  fully qualified video?

As an alternative, If anyone knows how to do this in [Whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) then kindly let me know

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you, that really works! you saved my day @Sid :-) i dont even know that these constraint even exist! ;-)

Comment: I have added ny comment as answer so that if it helped kindly upvote it and approve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help to make your video quality better -

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
    audio:false,
    video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                          chromeMediaSourceId: id,
                          maxWidth: 4000,
                          maxHeight: 4000 } }
  }, onMediaSuccess, getUserMediaError);
}
```

Comment: You saved me from a sleepless night dude.